# How to add columns to Infragistics UltraGrid without using designer

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I struggled with the Infragistics UltraGrid designer in Visual Studio 2015 because it keeps throwing errors when I tried to add and define columns without binding the data. I even explicitly chose to not bind data to it, but it throws the error anyway. After a while, I gave up and now I'm trying to manually add columns in C# without relying on the designer.

I tried to find ways to add columns in UltraGrid without relying on the designer, and I have found no useful data. I have tried looking in [Infragistics 2015 v2 Documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/ASPNET/2015.2/CLR4.0/) for "UltraGrid" and "UltraGrid Column" and they didn't have anything pertaining creating the columns without relying on the UltraGrid designer.

Does anyone know how I can add new columns to UltraGrid without relying on the UltraGrid designer?

Comment: can you add then in the code behind just like you would by creating an instance of the `UltraGrid`..?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If your question is can I do it by creating an instance of UltraGrid, then my answer will be I don't know how. I tried digging through Infragistics documentations and the documentations are not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have figured out the answer to this question on my own, and I figured it would benefit some people if I posted what I discovered here.

**1. First... Make headers by adding and defining columns**

**2. Next, add data**

**3. Finally, bind data.**

```
//Be sure to include this heading:
using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid;

public class ClassName{

    // 1. Make the Headers by adding and defining columns.
    private static DataTable MakeTableHeaders()
    {
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("My Table");
        // Declare variables for DataColumn and DataRow objects.
        DataColumn column;

        // Properties:
        // column.DataType   =  set data type (System.Int32, System.String, etc...)
        // column.ColumnName =  set column key (it MUST be unique) (String)
        // column.Caption    =  set the string to be visible for column header. (String)
        // column.ReadOnly   =  set whether the column is editable or not. (Boolean)
        // column.Unique     =  set whether or not values in the column must be unique.
        //                      Unique values = each cell must be different each other.
        //                      (Boolean)


        //// Program ID
        //// Caption "ID"
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "ID";
        column.Caption = "ID";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = true;
        // Adds the column to the programTable.
        myDataTable.Columns.Add(column);

        //// Program Name
        //// Caption "Program"
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Program";
        column.Caption = "Program";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = false;
        // Adds the column to the programTable.
        myDataTable.Columns.Add(column);

        // Add the rest of the necessary columns.
        // ....

        // When completed, return the table.
        return myDataTable;
    }

    // 2. Next, add data.
    public static DataSet loadData()
    {
        DataTable myDataTable = MakeTableHeaders();

        // Add a new empty data row to our data model.
        DataRow theDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();

        // Add data
        theDataRow[0] = 0;
        theDataRow[1] = "Program Name";

        // Add the DataRow to the table.
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(theDataRow);

        // Don't forget to accept changes,
        // or the data may not be retained.
        myDataTable.AcceptChanges();

        // Create a new DataSet.
        gridDataSet = new DataSet();

        // Add the table to DataSet.
        gridDataSet.Tables.Add(myDataTable);

        // Return the DataSet.
        return gridDataSet;
    }

    // 3. Finally, bind data.
    // Do it in the construct of your class
    public ClassName()
    {
        // Use the UltraGrid name you assigned to
        // your UltraGrid.
        ugMyUltraGrid.DataSource = loadData();
    }

    ugMyUltraGrid_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs)
    {
        // This is used to place columns in specific place.
        int headerPosition = 0;

        // Set cell editability
        // Activation.ActivateOnly = The context in the cell can be selected, but cannot be edited.
        // Activation.AllowEdit = Allows the cell to be edited.
        // Activation.Disabled = Disables the cell.
        // Activation.NoEdit = Only allows the cell to be activated.
        col.CellActivation = Activation.ActivateOnly;

        // Hide all columns
        col.Hidden = true;

        // Program ID
        column = "ID";
        ugColumn = e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column];
        e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].Header.Caption = "ID";
        e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].Header.VisiblePosition = headerPosition++;
        e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].Width = 50;
        // To size it to a fixed column width, use this instead:
        // e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].MinWidth = e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].MaxWidth = 50;

        // Program Name
        column = "Program";
        e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].Header.Caption = "Project";
        e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].Header.VisiblePosition = headerPosition++;
        e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].Width = 150;
        // To size it to a fixed column width, use this instead:
        // e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].MinWidth = e.Layout.Bands[parent].Columns[column].MaxWidth = 150;
    }
}
```

There you have it. :-)

Let me know if you run into issues, then I will do my best to help you.